# How do I allow a user to login with OAuth

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, oauth, spotify

I am currently building an application. The front-end is built in React and the back-end in Node. The application's primary purpose will be to provide interaction with Spotify on behalf of a user. I would like to allow users of my application to login with Spotify.

How do I go about achieving this?

I am currently able to successfully login with Spotify, hit my callback URI, obtain a token from Spotify, and make API calls on the user's behalf. However, how do I go about the initial login phase? Do I need to have a database of users (like I would for SPA) and then authenticate the users based on what is sent back from Spotify after login?

I'm just a bit confused about the overall flow and how my login process should be structured.

Comment: That depends, do you want to store any data related to the user or just provide functionality? If you just want to provide some functionality, then it's enough when the user is logged in trough spotify and you have a valid token. If you want to store more data related to your users, then you will have to add your own database and link the users

Comment: @Svdb thanks for replying! I want the users to be able to "log in", and then be presented with a dashboard where they can do certain things, some of these things may take a little while, so I want them to be able to log back in to check on the progress of the task they have initiated. I also want to be able to keep sessions, so that users don't have to login multiple times.

Comment: I'm not sure about the Spotify API, but I assume they return some kind of user id. So when your user registers, save this ID to the database. When they login, verify the token in your backend, if possible extract the user ID from it and look the user up from the database. Then the user can be logged into your own system from there on out and you keep the spotify token for their api interactions.

Comment: @Svdb Okay that sounds good to me. They do return a user ID, and I'm confident that it is guaranteed to be unique. If you want to post that as an answer, I can mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends, do you want to store any data related to the user or just provide functionality? If you just want to provide some functionality, then it's enough when the user is logged in trough Spotify and you have a valid token. If you want to store more data related to your users, then you will have to add your own database and link the users

I'm not sure about the Spotify API, but I assume they return some kind of user id. So when your user registers, save this ID to the database. When they login, verify the token in your back-end, if possible extract the user ID from it and look the user up from the database. Then the user can be logged into your own system from there on out and you keep the Spotify token for the api interactions.